# extracting the "time" from the file path

Tags: python, pandas, filepath

Editing previous question with respect the the dataframe:

I have a pandas dataframe where one column contains the file path, for example `path1/path2/path3/name/path4/hhmmss.tar.gz`. I want to loop over each line and extract the given name and corresponding hours, minutes and seconds given in the file path.
My output should be like:

```
for i in dataframe.file_path:
        code for extracting
        print(name, hours, min, sec)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why is `pandas` tagged? are these file paths in a Column in a DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to know the general principle for extracting. They are actually in the form of columns in the dataframe.

Comment: You'll end up with better answers if you make that clear in your future questions. Not all of the answers below will work on a column of data.

Comment: Ahh.. Alright. I will ask another question then with respect to the data frame involved. Thank you!

Comment: I also noticed looking at your profile you've never accepted an answer to a question. Accepting an answer to your question lets others know the question has been solved. There are several really great answers to choose from, on this and your previous question and consider clicking the checkmark to the left of whichever answer you feel best solves your problem. (See [What does it mean to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for information)

Comment: Gotcha mate!! Thank you for your suggestions.. :) I will definitely follow them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fname = 'archives/folder_name/name2/name3/name4/225422.tar.gz'
pos = fname.rindex('/') + 1 # get the position of the character following the last /
h, m, s = [fname[i:i + 2] for i in range(pos, pos + 5, 2)] # generate a list of three slices of 2 characters each, using list compehention, starting from the position found earlier and assign it to three variables
print(h, m, s)  # 22 54 22
```

Comment: Please add some clarification of what Your code does

Comment: The code does work. But, could you please add some clarification. Thank you!

Comment: comments have been added

Answer (score 2):

```
path = "archives/folder_name/name2/name3/name4/225422.tar.gz"

time = (path.split("/")[-1]).split(".")[0]
hours = time[0:2]
mins = time[2:4]
seconds = time[4:6]
```

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```py
import re

path = 'archives/folder_name/name2/name3/name4/225422.tar.gz'
   
pattern = re.compile(r'/(?P<hours>\d\d)(?P<minutes>\d\d)(?P<seconds>\d\d)\.tar\.gz$')
match = re.search(pattern, path)

print(match.groupdict() if match else None)
# {'hours': '22', 'minutes': '54', 'seconds': '22'}
```